# Problems setting a new node value in java, dom, xml parsing

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the following code:

```
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory_.newDocumentBuilder();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(s);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
Document doc_ = dBuilder.parse(inputSource);
```

and then I would like to create a new element in that node right under the root node with this code:

```
Node node = doc_.createElement("New_Node");
node.setNodeValue("New_Node_value");
doc_.getDocumentElement().appendChild(node);
```

The problem is that the node gets created and appended but the value isn't set. I don't know if I just can't see the value when I look at my xml if its hidden in some way but I don't think that's the case because I've tried to get the node value after the create node call and it returns `null`.
I'm new to xml and dom and I don't know where the value of the new node is stored. Is it like an attribute?

```
<New_Node value="New_Node_value" />
```

or does it put value here:

```
<New_Node> New_Node_value </New_Node>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks, Josh

Comment: Are you writing the new DOM back out to a file?  I don't see any reference to writing, and you're referring to looking at the xml.

Comment: @RD01 - Yea im writing it back out to a file.  I guess my main question at this point is what does node.setNodeValue() do if it doesn't set the text or the attribute?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The following code:

```
Element node = doc_.createElement("New_Node");
node.setTextContent("This is the content");  //adds content
node.setAttribute("attrib", "attrib_value"); //adds an attribute
```

produces:

```
<New_Node attrib="attrib_value">This is the content</New_Node>
```

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ah that does clarify, so what does node.setNodeValue() do?

Comment: `setNodeValue` varies based on the node type (Take a look at the table in the javadocs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html). If the node is an `Element` then setting nodeValue does nothing, because nodeValue is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

For clarification, when you create nodes use:

```
Attr x = doc.createAttribute(...);
Comment x = doc.createComment(...);
Element x = doc.createElement(...);   // as @dogbane pointed out
Text x = doc.createTextNode(...);
```

instead of using the generic Node for what you get back from each method.  It will make your code easier to read/debug.

Secondly, the `getNodeValue()` / `setNodeValue()` methods work differently depending on what type of Node you have.  See the summary of the [Node class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) for reference.  For an Element, you can't use these methods, although for a Text node you can.

As @dogbane pointed out, use `setTextContent()` for the text between this element's tags.  Note that this will destroy any existing child elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is other solution, in my case this solution is working because the setTextContent() function not exist. I am working with Google Web Toolkit (GWT) (It is a development framework Java) and I am imported the XMLParser library for I can use DOM Parser.

> import com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser;
>
> Document doc = XMLParser.createDocument();
>
> Element node = doc.createElement("New_Node");
>      node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("value"));
>
> doc.appendChild(node);

The result is:

> <`New_Node`> value <`/New_Node`>

Answer (score 0):

```
<New_Node value="New_Node_value" />
```

'value' is an attribute of

> New_Node

element, for getting into DOM I suggest you http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp

Comment: I know in that instance value is an attribute, but I don't know what value is when I setNodeValue and why the code I'm trying doesn't work.