# How to replace old value between XML tags with new value

Tags: java, xml, setattribute

I have to replace the `oldValue` in the date tag with the `newValue` in the below XML. I am using `setAttribute` function to do that but it doesn't seem to work. Please do let me know if I have to use a different function for replace text between tags.

*myfile.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<root>  
        <date>oldValue</date>  
</root>
```

*replace.java*

```
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("myFile.xml"));  
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();  
System.out.println("Before");  
System.out.println("Using getElementByTagName date: " + root.getElementsByTagName("date").item(0).getTextContent());  
System.out.println("Using getAttribute        date: " + root.getAttribute("date"));
root.setAttribute("date", "newValue");  
System.out.println("After");  
System.out.println("Using getElementByTagName date: " + root.getElementsByTagName("date").item(0).getTextContent());  
System.out.println("Using getAttribute        date: " + root.getAttribute("date"));
```

*Output:*

```
**Before**  
 Using getElementByTagName date: oldValue  
 Using getAttribute        date:  
 **After**  
 Using getElementByTagName date: oldValue  
 Using getAttribute        date: test
```

With the a lot of reading/experimentation, I have found `setAttribute()` works for replacing an XML like this. But, this doesn't work for me.

Comment: The text between an open and close XML tag is *not* an attribute. It's the content.

Comment: @Code-Guru You are correct. I was confusing attribute for content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [setTextContent(String textContent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent%28java.lang.String%29) method and not `setAttribute` method.

```
root.getElementsByTagName("date").item(0).setTextContent("newValue");
```

`oldValue` is the `TextContent` of `<date>` element, not attribute. Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) to find what is attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you set attribute you change attribute of node root, so it will be like `<root attrName = "attrValue"`>

There are questions which can help you to find an answer.

[Problems setting a new node value in java, dom, xml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681000/problems-setting-a-new-node-value-in-java-dom-xml-parsing)
[dynamically set value to xml using jdom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974766/dynamically-set-value-to-xml-using-jdom)

Comment: Thanks @Alexey those links were helpful.